# Merge 2 sorted time series algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, collections, merge

I have 2 time series that contain Bar objects, each Bar object contains a member variable of type long  and each time series  is stored within its own BlockingCollection. The time series is sorted in ascending order of the long values.

I like to devise a merge algorithm that allows me to take away the Bar that contains the long member variable of lowest value relative to the same comparison element in the other BlockingCollection.

Example, if the long value contained in the first Bar (bar1) in BlockingCollection1 is lower than the long value contained in the first Bar (bar2) in BlockingCollection2, then Take() from BlockingCollection1 and Add() to a MasterBlockingCollection, essentially ending up with a merged stream of Bar objects sorted by the value of each Bar's long member variable.

I like to later on extend to n BlockingCollections, not just 2. I played around with arrays that hold the long values to make the mapping easier but I think arrays are handier when working with pointers pertaining to this specific target algorithm.

I wonder whether anyone can point me to a Linq implementation and comment on how computationally expensive such approach is. I am asking because throughput is of importance as there are hundreds of millions of Bar objects flowing through the collections. If someone has a more clever idea than using Linq that would be very welcomed. I came across some ideas re merge algorithm at DrDobbs some time ago but cannot find the article anymore. In case it is not apparent by now, I target C# (.Net4.0)

Thanks a lot

Edit: I forgot to mention that the merging process is supposed to happen at the same time than workers who add new items to the blockingcollections (running on different tasks)

Comment: Try putting one in a SortedList which sorts the way you like, and then `AddRange` of the other list should be perfect.

Comment: @YoryeNathan, that would be O(n log n). This can be done in O(n).

Comment: @svick Only the initial sort would be O(n log n), but doesn't AddRange of SortedList handle it nicely in O(n)?

Comment: How does the fact that the collections are blocking going to affect you? Can we assume that all the collections are `IsCompleted` before the start of the merging? Or should the merging wait if some of the collections are empty for now?

Comment: @YoryeNathan: First, it couldn't do that, it would have to find the correct position for each element, which can't be done faster than O(log n). Second, `SoertedList` actually doesn't have `AddRange()`.

Comment: So a simple loop to go through items in list1 until it's the right index for list2[0]? Both lists are sorted in advance, right?

Comment: By the way, I confused SortedList with SortedSet

Comment: @Yorye, your suggestion does not seem to solve my problem. The overhead your idea introduces is just not feasible

Comment: @svick, very good comments (and some accompanying upvotes). You raised a good question: The fact its a blockingcollection in itself is not relevant but I forgot to state that workers are constantly on different tasks adding more items to the blockingcollections. The merging starts as soon as all blocking collections are full and ignores only those collections that are marked as completed for adding and are empty. But I need to think more about it maybe the merge algorithms needs to pull items rather than have independent workers add items to collections but generally the operation of ...

Comment: ...adding by a worker to one blocking collection should always be faster than the merge algorithm preventing empty blockingcollections even though more items arrive later on. The ignoring of finished blocking collections is simply accomplished through removing the blockingcollection that returns true on IsCompleted from a wrapping dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation of Merge. It should run in O(cN) time, where c is the number of collections. Is this what you're looking for?

```
    public static BlockingCollection<Bar> Merge(IEnumerable<BlockingCollection<Bar>> collections)
    {
        BlockingCollection<Bar> masterCollection = new BlockingCollection<Bar>();
        LinkedList<BarWrapper> orderedLows = new LinkedList<BarWrapper>();

        foreach (var c in collections)
            OrderedInsert(new BarWrapper { Value = c.Take(), Source = c }, orderedLows);

        while (orderedLows.Any())
        {
            BarWrapper currentLow = orderedLows.First.Value;
            orderedLows.RemoveFirst();

            BlockingCollection<Bar> collection = currentLow.Source;

            if (collection.Any())
                OrderedInsert(new BarWrapper { Value = collection.Take(), Source = collection }, orderedLows);

            masterCollection.Add(currentLow.Value);
        }
        return masterCollection;
    }

    private static void OrderedInsert(BarWrapper bar, LinkedList<BarWrapper> orderedLows)
    {
        if (!orderedLows.Any())
        {
            orderedLows.AddFirst(bar);
            return;
        }

        var iterator = orderedLows.First;
        while (iterator != null && iterator.Value.Value.LongValue < bar.Value.LongValue)
            iterator = iterator.Next;

        if (iterator == null)
            orderedLows.AddLast(bar);
        else
            orderedLows.AddBefore(iterator, bar);
    }

    class BarWrapper
    {
        public Bar Value { get; set; }
        public BlockingCollection<Bar> Source { get; set; }
    }

    class Bar
    {
        public Bar(long l)
        {
            this.LongValue = l;
        }
        public long LongValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I think `MergeSort` is a bad name for this function, because mergesort is something completely different. And it can be done faster, in O(N).

Comment: MergeSort is a two step algorithm for sort. The method above is effectively the second step. Merge would be a better name.

Comment: If you think it can be done faster, feel free to post a better solution. You're not going to get faster than O(cN).

Comment: @Shlomo, your solution works, it does not deal with conditions where collections may fall behind because worker tasks cannot keep up feeding new objects into the collections and erroneously signaling the algorithm that it can complete. But that was not part of the question, its just I need to think over the overall design.

Comment: @Shlomo, as mentioned your solution works but I am not sure whether it is the most efficient way. I thought about an alternative which is to throw all items up to a certain level (remember, comparer type is long) into one "bag" and then throw a sorting algorithm at it that may actually work more efficiently. Not only that but I could have several such bags that work in parallel, giving highest priority to the earlier bags to complete so that those can be added to the master blockingcollection when done. Any hints which sorting algoithms to look at?

Comment: As far as efficiency, you could make this a bit more efficient on a micro level, but you're not going to beat it substantially. It takes advantage of the fact that the child collections coming in are already sorted.

Comment: Is there some other information you want to provide? About how the concurrency is working? I'll add the micro improvement...

Comment: @Shlomo, I looked at k-way merge and similar related algorithms. The idea I had was to pick limited sequences each and use a divide and conquer algorithm, this could be performed in parallel by running several such algorithms at the same time.

Comment: If you merge in parallel, you'll have to re-merge later.

Comment: Not really, here is why: If I know that each sequence contains integer values sorted from lowest to highest from 1 to 1000, and if I am able to split up each sequence into 10 sub-sequences that contain values 1.100, 101.200, 201.300,..., 901.1000, then I can run 10 such k-way merge algorithms in parallel (on the 1.100 tuples, 101,200,...) and simply add the sorted resulting sequences together then I would not need to merge again, unless you call simply adding two sequences together as "merging". I still will mark your answer as the one I was looking for because it got me on the right path.

Comment: I chose a k-way merge with priority queue which ran orders of magnitudes faster even without parallelization. Key here is that it really wetted my appetite to delve more into this topic, thanks for your contributions and help on those. Hope the upvotes are welcomed.

Comment: Trying to understand solution: So if you have ten sequences 1-1000 say, so you split each sequence up into ten sub-sequences, giving you ten sequences from 1-100, another ten from 101-200, etc.. Then you merge the ten 1-100 sequences, and in parallel merge the ten 101-200 sequences. Afterwards you can just concatenate the result sequences for 1-100, 101-200, etc..

Comment: Was it faster because of the parallelism? I see how the divide, merge, concatenate enables parallelism. Ignoring benefits of parallelism, I don't see how you gain anything though.